# iOS8 Swift: Navigation and Tool Bars don't show up

Tags: ios8

NavigationBar and ToolBar are not showing in the simulator. I went through similar questions posted in this forum and included what I learnt from the answers. Still I'm unable to figure out why the bars are not shown. 
I also included the following lines to the viewWillAppear()

//Show toolbar and navbar

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

Below is the screenshot of my storyboard.
[image: Storyboard]

The simulator screenshot appears like
[image: Simulator]

I reach this view controller from a TableViewController (which is embedded in TabBarController) programmatically, with the following code

var nextController = ImagePickViewController()

nextController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImagePicker") as! ImagePickViewController

self.presentViewController(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks in advance
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Thank you James from Udacity. Posting his diagnosis.

The toolbars didn't show up because I used presentViewController. So the embedded navigation controller was bypassed and the ImagePickViewController was presented directly.

Solution is to start the navigation controller using the segueIdentifier. 
I added a segue from my TableViewController to the Navigation Controller (of the ImagePickViewController). In the attribute inspector for this segue, I set the Identifier as "startImagePicker". In the TableViewController code, I start the ImagePickViewController by calling performSegueWithIdentifier -

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startImagePicker", sender: self)

Thanks
Hari